# How to follow a user using tweetsharp?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

Following is my c# code. It is crashing Visualstudio on executing followuser method. My idea is one user has to follow another user. For Instance, A user with Email, password has to follow a user with screenname. Hope you help me on this.

I have got my user(ME) values, with this I am following a user with screename(someone).

TwitterService ts = new TwitterService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAuthenticationConsumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAuthenticationConsumerSecretKey"]);
        ts.AuthenticateWith(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAuthenticationToken"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAuthenticationTokenSecretKey"]);

```
    //need to provide username and password

    options.Q = "laxmanan90";
    options.IncludeEntities = true;
    var users = ts.SearchForUser(options);//Get list of users by query

    followoptions.ScreenName = "someone";
    followoptions.Follow = true;
    followoptions.UserId = 363817617;

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        try
        {
           var u = ts.FollowUser(followoptions);//Follow user
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me... Hopefully it fixes your problem.

```
public void followUser(string targetName)
    {
        twitter.FollowUser(new FollowUserOptions() { ScreenName = targetName });
    }
```